# Populating dynamic table with json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, mongodb

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>MongoDB Display</title>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var Obj = $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000", function(){
        alert("Success");

        $(Obj.rows).each(function(index, element){
            $(#tableID).append('<tr><td>' + element[1] + '</td><td><table><tr><td>'+ Obj.rows.scripts.element[0] 
            + '</td>' + "/" + '<td>' + Obj.rows.scripts.element[1] + '</td></tr></table></td></tr>');
        })
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <h1>H 1</h1>
        <table id="tableID" border = "1">
            <th>
                <td>PAGE</td>
                <td>SCRIPTS</td>
            </th>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In short;

I have a MongoDB ready to be displayed at localhost:3000. Server is running and I can display the data on the browser with `localhost:3000` But when i try to run the above code on the browser, all i can get the js `Alert("Success")` and the hard coded part of the table. PAGE and SCRIPTS...

the data is:

```
{
    "offset": 0,
        "rows": [
            {
                "_id": {},
                "url": "http://www.qweq.com\r",
                "totalLines": 3084,
                "scripts": [
                    {
                        "line": 111,
                        "tag": "\"asdas/etc/designs/qwe/assets/head-5.30.31.min.js\""
                    },{
                        "line": 3065,
                        "tag": "\"asdas/etc/designs/qwe/assets/common-5.30.31.min.js\""
                    },{
                        "line": 3067,
                        "tag": "\"asda/etc/designs/qwe/assets/category-5.30.31.min.js\""
                    }
                ]
            },{
                "_id": {},
                "url": "http://www.qweqsd.com/qwdq23/qweq/qweqw/\r",
                "totalLines": 3042,
                "scripts": [
                    {
                        "line": 113,
                        "tag": "\"asda/etc/designs/asd/assets/head-5.30.31.min.js\""
                    },{
                        "line": 3023,
                        "tag": "\"asdasd/etc/designs/asd/assets/common-5.30.31.min.js\""
                    },{
                        "line": 3025,
                        "tag": "\"asdad/etc/designs/qwe/assets/category-5.30.31.min.js\""
                    }
                ]
            },
```

How can I make this Json data to be display in a dynamic table?

Thank you.

Comment: $.getJSON wont return something, its an async function, your function handler should receive the result as argument: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version is kind of working :) Maybe you'll find inspiration.

```
$(rows).each(function(index,element){
    console.log(index); console.log(element);
    $('#tableID').append('<tr><td>' + index + '</td><td>'+ element['url'] 
                         + '</td>' + "/" + '<td>' + JSON.stringify(element['scripts']) + '</td></tr></table>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fw4f5L72/1/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing quotes around the table name. Instead, you should have something like `$('#tableID')`.

Additionally, you'll want your function call to include the data that it's returning to you. For example:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:3000", function(data){
        alert("Success");
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Then, `data` will include the JSON object, and you can manipulate it however you please.

Comment: Right, I forgot to type it.

Comment: OK, Sounds good. I wasn't aware of that fact. Pretty new here. Now I'm trying to access some of the data to append it to <td> Can you give me a small example how to do it accordingly to my data?

Comment: See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3f5g09q8/) JSFiddle for example. You'll have to consider how you want the script array to be shown. In the example that I've given, I've only included the first script in the array.